# Windows has had a BSoD, sfc /scannow not working

Tags: windows, boot, recovery, sfc

yesterday my windows 10 PC went trough a update, after it it worked normally, during the night I was compiling resources for a Linux OS in Virtual Box and after 1 hour or so I had a blue screen of death.

Windows tries to make automatic repairs, runs a diagnostic and opens the windows recovery environment. When trying to open saved checkpoints windows shows 3 restore checkpoints and if selected to show more it shows one more, but when trying to login on any of those checkpoints the process is interrupted saying that the system was not able to restore to that point.

Automatic repair option in the recovery environment doesn’t seem to do anything that the initialisation automatic repair doesn’t try to do and returns to the recovery environment.

Opening the cmd from the recovery environment and trying to run sfc /scannow returns :"Windows Resource Protection could not perform the required operation", then I tried using chkdsk on both my main ssd and additional hard drive, it seemed as if the ssd were Windows is installed had some problems that chkdsk appears to have solved since calling it again does not return those same messages, among them it appears that there was free space in the disk that seemed to having been interpreted as occupied space.

Although after running chkdsk and reinitiating the computer I still run in the same problems as before. sfc /scannow still gives that same message.

Then I tried to run Bootrec /fixMbr, which seemed to be sucessful but then Bootrec /fixboot gives me a acess denied reply, in this moment it seems to me as if the cmd in recovery mode is not running as administrator which could explain why sfc /scannow does not work and neither Bootrec /fixboot also doesn’t.

Also when opening C:\Windows\System32\Logfiles\Srt\SrtTrail.txt the closest thing that looked like a error was in:

"Name: Check for installed LCU

Result: Completed successfully. Error code = 0xc1 "

But the file ends with "Startup Repair has tried several times but still cannot determine the cause of the problem."

Even in the beginning when I tried to recover the system maintaining only my files it also did not work it appeared 1% and gave a message about undoing what it had done and that it was not possible to recover the system.

What I find strange is that I can access all my files trough the windows recovery environment cmd, which does not seem to imply large scale memory corruption, I think that if I could get sfc /scannow running all would be fixed.

**EDIT:** I just tried to run sfc /scannow from C:\Windows\System32 instead of from X:\Windows\System32 and got "This version of C:\Windows\System32\sfc.exe is not compatible with the version of Windows being executed. Verify the informations of the system of the computer and contact the supplier of the software."
Doesn’t that mean that the problem **is** in the windows update since X: and C: have different and incompatible versions of sfc?

**NEW EDIT:** I have also tried to run sfc /verifyonly this results in "The Windows Resource Protection found integrity violations. For online repairs, the details are included in the CBS log file localized in windir\Logs\CBS\CBS.log so I decided to open the CBS.log in C:\Windows\Logs\CBS\CBS.log but the last entry was of yesterday and it appears to be from the update with TrustedInstaller, TiWorker and other such calls, the file ending with Ending TrustedInstaller finalization at 11:13:59 which is strange since I remember the update taking place at around 02:25:16 which is in fact were the previous set of entries begin in CBS.log , but no entry appears to be from the just run sfc /verifyonly.

**NEW NEW UPDATE:** After searching for verifiable evidence that there is something wrong with my SSD and/or HD, since that appears to be a "common place" with what regards to what the problem is with my computer, the following is a image of the cmd of the Windows Recovery Environment after using commands to get the SMART status of both drives (the part before that was I running chkdsk on my drives again, it is in Portuguese because my system is in Portuguese, but the result of SMART is in English anyway.).

[image]

**Update Update:** so after losing time with silly considerations for ssd failing, which it is not, It appears that I have randomly tripped on the **actual** problem, it seems that my BCD file is either corrupted or has some other problem, when invoking "bcdboot C:\Windows /s N: /f ALL" I get the following error: "BFSVC error:could not open the BCD template store. Status = [c000015c]" when going to C:\Windows\System32\config there is a BCD-template that supposedly is used to recreate the BCD template in the Boot directory, going to such a directory that is a unnamed occult FAT32 partition that I have named N: and going to N:\EFI\Microsoft\Boot there is a BCD file there, I have saved the old BCD as BCD.bak and tried to create a new BCD, with BCDBOOT but still got the same error, although a new BCD was present at the N:\EFI\Microsoft\Boot folder, it still doesn’t work, so I think that the BCD-template was corrupted and is creating bad BCD in the boot directory, is there a way to repair this BCD-template file without a Windows install CD? And if it can be done only with a install CD what are the exact steps that one should take, and will this erase all my files or make all installed programs stop working?

Comment: The fact Windows is unable to repair itself suggests an underlying storage issue. The fact you can access your files is important, since it will allow you to backup your files, but that doesn’t help with corrupt system files. The command to attempt to repair the system files is failing due to what likely is explainable by the fact your system drive is starting to fail.

Comment: Some people might argue with me but I have been doing this since the beginning of Microsoft (and I work there).  I have yet to have DISM or SFC *solve* diddly squat.. I am mostly sure other people have had success with it but I have not.  I agree with @Ramhound but my first suggestion (after a backup) would be to create a Windows USB stick and do an actual repair install.. I doubt it will fix it because as Ramhound points out.. I too think your drive is probably failing.

Comment: I have seen DISM and SFC correct certain problems but once the system doesn’t boot its far to late to fix the problem causing it not to boot

Comment: In most cases this is not a hardware issue, but the usual procedure of Windows destroying itself with a failed update. The average usage time of a Windows Desktop Installation before it fails is worldwide a tad below 3 years. Reinstall or restore from backup.

Comment: @EugenRieck - I have after 30 years, have never once had Windows destroy itself, I have had system drives fail that happened after a Windows Update

Comment: You are lucky or have a tiny sample. I am responsible for 10..000+ Windows installations and every patch cycle a few of the just don't come back in working order. Their virtual harddrives are on the same storage system as their brethren, who come back fine.

Comment: What makes me angry is that if the hard drive is beginning to fail but I can still access all of its contents, shouldn’t those utilites that supposedly repair or run diagnostics on windows also be able to read the files and give a useful diagnostic report about where the system is failing? The only I could find is SrtTrail.txt and the file ends with a message about not being able to find where the error lies, where else can I look for diagnostic telemetry?

Comment: Also why do I get acess denied for Bootrec /fixboot? Is there a way to force it to run like in linux where one can write sudo before the command and at least the access is not denied?

Comment: @FelipeDilho You might want to do a RAM test. Also, remember that every time a drive write happens, it is another chance for the drive to fail to the point you can't get your data back.

Comment: @AndrewMorton As I said the majority of my files are in a secondary Hard Drive the system is in a SSD with only the windows and some programs that run faster on SSD, for a moment can we suggest other possibilities beyond easily considering that "ah, its just your SSD failing"? Like how can I force sfc, Bootrec /fixboot and DISM to actually run? I don't think they are actually running since the log files don't show any new info from them running.

Comment: @FelipeDilho Maybe the RAM is failing. Data is stored in RAM before it goes to the disk. Failing SATA cables can also create disk problems. If the software you're trying to run cannot run correctly, but can detect it can't run correctly, more informative error messages from those programs could be helpful, but they weren't written to do so.

Comment: It is not RAM, Windows Memory Diagnostic Tool in advanced mode running in 4 passes did not find any problem.

Answer (score 1):

Hard drives *may* gradually degrade (though they can also fail abruptly), being able to both read and write with just a few bad sectors, which can be mapped out, if not too bad.

SSD's tend to fail more dramatically. If [one is *lucky*, the drive locks, preventing writing](https://www.techtarget.com/searchstorage/tip/4-causes-of-SSD-failure-and-how-to-deal-with-them) to make data recovery possible. "The best you can hope for is a loss of the ability to write to the drive, but retaining the ability to read from it." ; Therefor, DISM and SFC can no longer *write* to repair anything on the drive.

1. Recover all the data you can, or make an additional image of the drive, using bootable media, e.g.,USB flash drive.
2. Test the SSD. Most likely, it can no longer write.
3. If the SSD is usable, reinstall Windows from ISO, keeping files.
4. If it's dead, replace SSD and restore image, then perform repairs, which is least effort, or,
5. Replace SSD, install Windows *de novo* and restore files and applications (where feasible) from image.

Comment: I actually think my C: drive which is a SSD is fine, it is way newer than my additional storage D: hardrive and I don’t install almost anything on it, also I was able to create a testfile.txt on my C:\Users\Felipe\Desktop and write in it with a copy con filename.txt, opening testfile.txt I see exactly what I typed. Also I tryed to read the sfc /scannow output with the command ** findstr /c: "[SR]" C:\Windows\logs\CBS\CBS.log >sfcdetails.txt** fond in: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-client/deployment/analyze-sfc-program-log-file-entries   but the file was empty.

Comment: Can't it be a problem with permissions? Since I am running the cmd available from Windows Recovery Environment can it be that for some reason this cmd is not running with administrator privileges and therefore neither sfc or Bootrec /bootfix are actually being run? I just tried to run DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /ScanHealth and got error: 193 error in acessing the binaries DISM in the system host. Verify if the DISM binaries exist and if you have permission of reading the paste.

Comment: Yes, it must be run as administrator. If you can open CMD as admin, e.g. pressing Windows, typing CMD and press Shift+Alt+Enter, that should work... if you can do that in Recovery. Otherwise, reinstall from ISO, keeping files.

Comment: @FelipeDilho, you may think all you want but you'd need to verify that. for example what does SMART look like?

Comment: @JoepvanSteen I am all in favor of verifying things, part of my critique is that people have been hypothesising things without suggesting anything to verify if that is the case or other measures that can be used to repair, I have just run SMART commands that I didn’t know to verify the state of the drives and I will be putting the image with the commands and the results in the question, as you can see SMART doesn’t verify any problems with my drives either the SSD or the additional HD, so there is no measurable evidence that the problem is the SSD.

Comment: Hi, best would be if we can see RAW values, so a report/screenshot from Victoria for Windows for example. I'm sorry I should have been more precise.

Comment: I am currently running advanced Windows Memory Diagnostics Tool to see if there is any problems with my RAM, I had just done two passes of the standard test and it detected no problems in the status while it was being run, i don't know where to read the file from that but after it finishes I will look where it is and then I will try to download this Victoria program with curl from the cmd of the Windows Recovery Environment, but it may take some time since i never used curl, and I don’t know if the internet is currently working on my computer since it isn’t doing a login.